# Deploying a simple grails 3.x app to Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment

I am having issues when trying to deploy an application to a tomcat 7 instance. A little background. All I did was create an app (create-app) and simple controller (create-controller) hello with a method that just renders "Hello World". Now the application works fine when running with the "grails run-app" command. When i try to deploy it to tomcat however I get an error message. I have edited the configure to have "provided" for the embedded tomcat (was keeping from deploying war successfully).

The war will extract successfully and create a folder with all the assets. If war is named sample.war tomcat will create a folder called sample and all assets are placed there. When I goto the Url (localhost:8080/sample) i get a 404 error but if i goto localhost:8080/sample/hello it renders correctly. The issue i'm having is from a more complex application but i figured i would start small by successfully deploying this hello world app. Everything is "out of the box" so to speak so i'm not sure if anything else other then the runtime tomcat-starter had to be changed.

I am completely new to the Java/Grails world so i'm not very familiar with certain things - but looking through the logs/catalina.out file i am not seeing anything that is jumping out at me.

Comment: Which OS are you using? How did you install tomcat? What is your Java version? You can't deploy application with file based DB in Linux because of permission issues.

Comment: Does the url localhost:8080/sample render *hello* when using `grail run-app` yet the same url renders a 404 when deployed as a war file?

Comment: Check out url mapping section in official docs.

Comment: OS - Centos 6.7, Installed from the tomcat website. got the tar.gz extracted to /usr/local/tomcat7. Java home 1.8.0.66. For production the database is a MYSQL DB on a different machine.. The URL when i issue grails run-app the context root is just / so localhost:8080/hello renders the index of controller hello. Was a little reluctant on looking at URL mapping as it works fine in "development" mode.